# How to compare columns with both strings and integers? Python Pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, integer

I have a pandas DataFrame with two columns, one with both integers (1-23) and strings (X or Y) and one with numbers only. I want to compare if the values are equal. I tried among others:

```
np.where(np.equal(item from column a, item from column b), 1, 0)
```

But this doesn't work since there are strings in there. I also cant turn all the values into integers due to the X and Y. Any advice?

Comment: provide a code example of how your data frame looks like or print(df.head()) or something of that kind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas is accommodating with type comparisons. You can use `pd.Series.__eq__` as with a regular comparison between two series of the same type.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 'hello', 4.5, 'text', 6, 7, 'errr', 9, 'test'],
                   'col2': range(1, 11)})

df['compare'] = (df['col1'] == df['col2']).astype(int)

print(df)

    col1  col2  compare
0      1     1        1
1      2     2        1
2  hello     3        0
3    4.5     4        0
4   text     5        0
5      6     6        1
6      7     7        1
7   errr     8        0
8      9     9        1
9   test    10        0
```

Comment: This works and is very understandable, thank you! In my case, I have an if statement that needs to run if the values are equal, e.g: if (df['col1'] == df['col2']).astype(int): print('these values are equal'). This gives me an attributeErrow: AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'astype'. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: `that needs to run if the values are equal`. This needs careful definition. Do you mean if *all* the values are equal, *any* of the values are equal, or you want to print some value *for each row*?

Comment: Thank you for the fast response! Lets say I want to compare the two columns row by row. For instance, if col1 row1 == 8 and col2 row 2 == 8, then print('these values are equal'). I have a working code with a for loop, but it fails if one of the items is an int.

Comment: Ah I see, I guess that would be a different question. Would you mind asking it as a separate question? It's hard to write code in comments. (You may also get more options from other contributors.)